What is this enigmatic IT?
In a distant realm, two entities are confined, unable to exchange even a whisper. Their freedom hinges on synchronization, yet communication is forbidden.
Each will face a decision: to act or to refrain. The mystery lies in "IT"—the harbinger of their fate.
Should both receive IT, they must diverge in their actions. If not, they must not diverge.
What is this enigmatic IT?

You can accept an answer if you think it is the best. Just click the tick mark next to the answer.


 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_inequality#CHSH_game


 Alice and Bob are the two agents. Charlie determines whether they recieve IT.


A better solution to "I have to add more text" would be to explain, in a sentence or two, why this answer fits the parts of the riddle.
